# Как ускорить разворачиваение бэкапа MySQL

Tags: mysql, оптимизация, производительность, резервное-копирование

Имеется бэкап баз данных размером чуть более 2Gb. Бэкап сделан штатными средствами через mysqldump.

Разворачивается бэкап на новом сервере очень долго, более 2 часов.

Как можно более быстро развернуть бэкап MySQL? Или как создать более быстрый (для развертывания) бэкап?

PS по структуре этот бэкап состоит из 2000 маленьких баз данных и 1 большой БД (1 очень большая таблица).

Answer (score 3):

> Как можно более быстро развернуть бэкап MySQL?

Можно на время развёртывания отключить индексы и внешние ключи, которые затем создать/установить на уже развёрнутых данных. Будет немножко быстрее.

> как создать более быстрый (для развертывания) бэкап?

Самый быстрый вариант - использовать тупо файловую копию (Raw Data Backup). Впрочем, восстановление в этом случае не совсем тривиально, хотя и не чрезмерно сложно.

Не самое плохое - отдельный бэкап структуры и отдельный - данных (SELECT INTO OUTFILE + LOAD DATA INFILE). Но и тут отключение индексации способствует.

Ну и вообще неплохо бы внимательно проштудировать [официальную документацию по резервному копированию и восстановлению](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/backup-and-recovery.html,). И не забыть раздел по [репликации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-solutions-backups.html), там тоже кое-что есть интересного.